# Cocos2d app working on all device except iPhone 4 (any OS) with CCBatchnode just showing black screen after addchild

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, screen

I've developed an app call Linsanity Rush for iPhone and I've tested on iPhone Simulator (normal/retina), iPad simulator, iPad2 iOS 5.0.1, iPhone 4S and all working fine. However, some users from iPhone 4 complain about game just showing black screen except the mute and pause button after clicking the start game button.

Xcode Version is 4.2.1
Mac Version 10.7.2
Cocos2d Version cocos2d v2.0.0-beta

I've tested about this on different OS on iPhone 4 and all having the same problem. I've checked my code and I found out that the graphic that I add using the `CCBatchnode` all just showing black screen. This explain why the users only able to see the mute and pause button because those 2 buttons are not `addChild` by using the `CCBatchnode`.

Additional information about this problem, I'm not sure is it the `CCBatchNode` having problem because I've used `CCBatchNode` in the main menu as well and the iPhone 4 Users are able to see the images on main menu, problem only occur when they go into the game which is on different source file and I replace the scene with game play.

However, I've spent a long time searching on the net and can't find anything error that similar to me which only happen on iPhone 4. I have totally no idea what would cause this so I don't know which part of source code I should post at here.

Comment: CCBatchNode can only use one texture. Are you trying to add sprites to the batch from different textures?

Comment: @Matisse: doing so would assert and would cause the issue on any device. I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer for this problem. Previously I just test with Iphone 4S and iPad2. When I test using iPhone 4 and 3GS, I get the message in XCode show that :

cocos2d: WARNING: Image (1024 x 4096) is bigger than the supported 2048 x 2048.

This is because if I want to support iPhone 3GS or iPhone 4, the image that I create using Zwoptex cannot be larger than (2048 x 2048) (The one that im using currently is 4096 x 4096). I've solved this by create multiple spritesheet and divide the images into smaller list.

Hopefully if there is someone that having the same problem know how to solve this.